# Jquery Autocomplete _renderItem does not work when Function is called a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I wanted to generate two input fields with an autocomplete that generates Icons. I used `_renderItem` but realised, that - by calling the autocomplete using a single class for multiple input fields - the second field does not call the `_renderItem` function:

See here:

```js
var $project = $('.project');


var projects = [{
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
    icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
  }
];

$project.autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: projects,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    this.val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  }
});

$project.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

  var $li = $('<li>'),
    $img = $('<img>');


  $img.attr({
    src: 'https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/images/' + item.icon,
    alt: item.label
  });

  $li.attr('data-value', item.label);
  $li.append('<a href="#">');
  $li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label);

  return $li.appendTo(ul);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="project-label">This one works:</div>
<input class="project">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="project-label">This one does not show Images in the List:</div>
<input class="project">
```

How comes that in the second autocomplete Input-Field the images are not shown. How can I get it working. 
Since in my Website I am using php to generate the fields automatically and have only one autocompletefunction overall, I am calling the autocomplete via the class. Is there another possibility? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it with [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) so it will called for each item in the collection.

> <sub>Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.</sub>

```js
var $project = $('.project');


var projects = [{
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
    icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
  }
];

$project.autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: projects,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    this.val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  }
});

$project.each(function() {
  var $proj = $(this);
  
  $proj.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var $li = $('<li>'),
      $img = $('<img>');


    $img.attr({
      src: 'https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/images/' + item.icon,
      alt: item.label
    });

    $li.attr('data-value', item.label);
    $li.append('<a href="#">');
    $li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label);

    return $li.appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="project-label">This one works:</div>
<input class="project">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="project-label">This one does not show Images in the List:</div>
<input class="project">
```

Comment: Hey. Quick answer and I can tell: It works! Thanks a lot for helping out.